# gulp livereload - Multiple filters

Tags: filter, gulp, livereload

I am using a gulp webserver in combination with a nodejs to test my api. 
They are both within the same directory, so as soon as my mock-data changes, gulp performs a livereload. 
I wanted to add filters to the livereload.
Adding my first filter worked just fine, but with two it doesn't reload ever.

```
gulp.task('webserver',['watch:js', 'watch:sass', 'watch:html'], function() {
  gulp.src('./')
    .pipe(server({
      defaultFile: "dist/app.component.html",
      livereload:  {
        enable: true,
        filter: function(fileName){
         if (!(fileName.match(/.git/) | fileName.match(/.nodejs_srv/))) {

                        return true;

                    } else {

                        return false;

                    }
      }},
      open: true
    }));
});
```

Edited filter function:

```
function(filePath, cb) {
          cb( !(/.git/.test(filePath)) );
      }}
```

I don't know how to add fitlers to this, newbe over here.

Comment: You did not use a logical or `||` between the filters. Try `fileName.match(/.git/) || fileName ...`

Comment: Whups. But it doesnt work either. Somehow it now doesnt even work with one path. I will edit this post with the one-path-filter function I had before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution myself. 
It's

```
function(filePath, cb) {
          cb( !(/.git/.test(filePath)) &&
              !(/nodejs_srv/.test(filePath));
      }}
```

Comment: Ok, that will work but that's the same as `cb( ! (/.git/.test(filePath) ||          /nodejs_srv/.test(filePath)));` It just a boolean variation. `!a && !b == !( a || b)`. Please mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Aaah, my first try was !(a) || !(b), so that might've been my mistake. Have to wait two day to accept, though.

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgott (two days).  Sorry.  And yes your first try was wrong. But I think you learned a lot from this. That's the best learning: Making mistakes and find out what went wront.

Answer (score 1):

You droped the callback `cb`. I do not know livereload very well. But if it relies on a callback, you must call this callback.

```
gulp.task('webserver',['watch:js', 'watch:sass', 'watch:html'], function()
{
  gulp.src('./')
    .pipe(server({
      defaultFile: "dist/app.component.html",
      livereload:  {
        enable: true,
        filter: function(fileName, cb)
        {
           cb(!(fileName.match(/.git/) || fileName.match(/.nodejs_srv/)));
        }
      },
      open: true
    }));
});
```

I just typed in my example, no syntax check. Hopefully, it works out of the box.

The callback gets a boolean value as a parameter that indicates if the the file should be taken `true` or not `false`.

Comment: I found a solution and I'd like to facepalm myself. I had to use && instead of || and everything works fine. Well, that happens if you use a function provided with no explanation. Anyway, thanks to you!

Comment: Sorry I think you made a mistake. If you use an and `&&` then, you test for the file not to be like ".git" AND like ".nodejs_srv" at the same time, which is allways true.

Comment: As I still don't know HOW it works and what  it does, since I can't find any proper explanation for this anywhere, the only thing that I can say is, that it works. If you say it shouldn't.. well. Then I'm really confused. :(

Comment: The caller of the filter function might check if you return a value or not. In this case the return value must be a real `true` or `false` not falsy or truely. (In JavaScript it is possible to interpret certain values as false (undefined, "", 0, null) or true (all the others).)   If you return nothing or `undefined` the caller expects a callback function. So probably it might work without a callback. But if you use a `&&` as you  did, the result will allways be `true` because the file name cannot have two values at the same time. Your filter did not exclude anything.

Comment: I just couldn't help, and checked the code of the server life reload. ;-) The version I saw needs a callback in any case. It does not check the return value as I suspected in my last comment. So you have to work with a callback.

Comment: Here's where I got my solution from: http://www.angular.rocks/Angular2-Gulp-Workflow/   sadly there isn't any explanation either. It's the last code-snippet on that page. All I can say is, that it works. I've tested it a few times by now, changing files in nodejs_srv doesnt trigger a livereload anymore. If only there where explanations. I only started a month ago, so there's a lot to learn for me.

Comment: Ok sorry, I saw your answer above to late. You did not only exchanged the || with a && but also changed the negation of terms. That answer is correct.